# Read Omnesys NEST streaming data using API

Tags: stocks

The task is related to Share market.

Currently Omnesys NEST trading terminal provides streaming data for NSE and MCX and so. They also provide an option to link the live share streaming data to EXCEL sheet, and the the market changes are updating to excel sheet for every second.

This is the function used in EXCEL to read the data from NEST terminal:

```
=RTD("nest.scriprtd",,"mcx_fo|GOLDM15SEPFUT","LTP")
```

Can anybody help me to extract the live streaming data?

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific ? Do you want to develop some live trading strategy using the live data , or do you want to store this data in some database or ....
As an example, you can use pandas DataFrame to retrieve this data into your python program and process it.

---

UPD:

The NSE NOW terminal is based on Omnesys Nest. I have automated this using [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) Check out this [link:](https://sites.google.com/a/ayamih.com/blog/home/automatingthensenowterminal)  . The live streaming data from the market watch of Omnesys Nest can be extracted using AutoIt

The github repo for the program is [Here](https://github.com/pavanmullapudy/automating_nse_now_terminal)

Comment: This is better asked as a comment.

Comment: Then I did not have the required privileges to add as a comment. Now I do.